# Get Date As String and Remove Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a simple problem. i need to get only the date as string and remove its time.
How can i do this? I tried new Date() but its not working.

```
const value = '2018-04-09 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Uh, just use bog standard string methods to chop off the time? Why wouldn't that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const formattedDate = ''
  + currentDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-'
  + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-'
  + currentDate.getFullYear();

console.log(formattedDate)

// output
"09-05-2019"
```

Comment: How can i add '0' if the month or date has single digits like number 1-9?

Comment: You can use [String.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) for that. e.g: `singleDigitNumber.toString().padStart(2, '0');`

Comment: Can you edit your answer? Thanks

Comment: Okay. updated ^^

Comment: Thanks. Pls upvote me.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function yyyymmdd(date) {
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
  var dd = date.getDate();

  return [date.getFullYear(),
          (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
          (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
         ].join('-');
};

let date=new Date()
console.log(yyyymmdd(date))
```

Comment: date.getMonth is not a function

Comment: `date.getMonth ` it function only, you can try like this: `console.log(typeof(date.getMonth))` it will print "function"